# How to pass error from extension service worker to content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chromium, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, browser-extension

I have a browser extension in which my content script requests information from a background script (service worker). Usually, this works fine, but in some cases the information cannot be retrieved by the background script. In that case, I want the background script to send the content script an error containing some information about the nature of the problem.

However, when sending an error via the `sendResponse` function, the content script receives only an empty object. Why does this happen and how can I send an error from the background script to the content script?

`content-script.js`:

```js
const showResult = (res) => {
  console.log('Received the following response from background script:\n', res);
};

chrome.runtime.sendMessage('send me a user!').then((res) => showResult(res));
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('send me a user!').then((res) => showResult(res));
```

`background-script.js`:

```js
const responses = [
  new Error('something bad happened'),
  { name: 'John Doe', age: 38 }
];

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  const response = responses.pop()
  console.log('Going to send the following response:\n', response);
  sendResponse(response);
});
```

`manifest.json`:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "A test",
  "version": "0.0.1",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }
  ],

  "background": {
    "type": "module",
    "service_worker": "background-script.js"
  }
}
```

Console output from `background-script.js`:

```
Going to send the following response:
 {name: 'John Doe', age: 38}
-------------------------------------------------------
Going to send the following response:
 Error: something bad happened
    at background-script.js:2:3
```

Console output from `content-script.js`:

```
Received the following response from background script:
 {name: 'John Doe', age: 38}
-------------------------------------------------------
Received the following response from background script:
 {}
```

Browser: Chromium Version 115.0.5790.170 (Official Build)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of your empty object is likely because [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage` requires `message` to be JSON serializable](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-sendMessage), and `new Error()` is not.

To directly pass the error information, you'll want to do something like:

```js
const error = new Error('something bad happened');
const serializedError = JSON.stringify({
  message: error.message,
  name: error.name,
  stack: error.stack
});
```